# efficiently converting hex to binary

Tags: java, binary, hex

In the following program I'm converting a hex String "0123456789ABCDEF" into binary.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String key = "0123456789ABCDEF"; //hexadecimal key
    char[] keyCharArray = key.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < key.length(); i++) {
        System.out.print(HexToBinary((keyCharArray[i]))+",");
    }
}

public static String HexToBinary(char Hex) {
    int i = Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(Hex), 16);
    String Bin = Integer.toBinaryString(i);
    return Bin;
}
```

I'm getting the following output

```
0,1,10,11,100,101,110,111,1000,1001,1010,1011,1100,1101,1110,1111,
```

but i require the output to be as follows

```
0000,0001,0010,0011,0100,0101,0110,0111,1000,1001,1010,1011,1100,1101,1110,1111,
```

one way I found is appending `0x` in front of each hex character. 
as follows:

```
0x0, 0x1, 0x2,............,0xE,0xF
```

another way is to manually check how many characters the output is short of 4, and append those many `0`'s to it. But I do not know how to implement the former in the above code. Is there any efficient method to do what im trying to do above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always do a static lookup:

```
private static String[] staticLookup = new String[]
    {0000,0001,0010,0011,0100,0101,0110,0111,
     1000,1001,1010,1011,1100,1101,1110,1111};


public static String HexToBinary(char Hex) {
    return staticLookup[Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(Hex), 16)];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, both answers are correct as per my requirements, but i'd rather go for the efficient one, Thanks :)

Answer (score 6):

```
String.format("%04d", yournumber);
```

To Be clear:

```
public static String HexToBinary(char Hex) {
    int i = Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(Hex), 16);
    return String.format("%04d", Integer.parseInt(Integer.toBinaryString(i)));
}
```

Comment: He doesn't have a number, he has a string. So, `String.format("%04s", Bin)`.

Comment: This will create the String from the number with padding. Check his HexToBinary() method where he creates int i

Comment: @Joao Oh, you meant the variable "yournumber", I was just giving a general case of the method()...

Comment: toBinaryString returns a String, not a number, so I think that'll throw an exception, I think. Replace your `d`s with `s`s and you're golden. :)

Comment: thanks. But, either way it throws `java.util.FormatFlagsConversionMismatchException` exception

Comment: it works. did the following 

`return String.format("%04d", Integer.parseInt(Integer.toBinaryString(i)));`

Comment: but I'm not sure whether thats the most efficient method, if there was a way in which i could get each of my hex characters as `0x0, 0x1, 0x2, ..... , 0xF` then i think that would be better

Comment: If efficiency is your thing, I added a reply with a static lookup.

Answer (score 2):

simply use a `switch` to determine the number of missing zeros:

```
switch(i){
    case 0: case 1: return "000" + Integer.toBinaryString(i);
    case 2: case 3: return "00" + Integer.toBinaryString(i);
    case 4: case 5: case 6: case 7:  return "0" + Integer.toBinaryString(i);
    default: return Integer.toBinaryString(i);
}
```